# Why does strtok() make my program return negative value?

Tags: c, strtok

I have a program in which I want to read text from a file and then store it in an array of structures. I tried to do it with strtok(). Here's code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct kon {
    char name[50];
    int year;
    char city[50];
};
typedef struct kon kon;

int main(void) {
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen("kon.txt", "r");

    if (!input) {
        printf("No such file");
    }
    else {
        kon *tab;
        char line[256], year_tmp[10], *token;
        int counter = 0, max_tab = 2, year;

        tab = (kon*)malloc(max_tab * sizeof(kon));

        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), input) != EOF) {
            if(line) {
                token = strtok(line, ", ");

                strcpy(tab[counter].name, token);
                token = strtok(NULL, ", ");

                strcpy(year_tmp, token);
                year = atoi(year_tmp);
                tab[counter].year = year;
                token = strtok(NULL, ", ");

                strcpy(tab[counter].city, token);

                printf("%s, %d, ", tab[counter].name, tab[counter].year);
                printf("%s\n", tab[counter].city);

                counter++;
            }

            /* Reallocing memory for array if needed */
            if(counter == max_tab - 1) {
                max_tab += 2;
                tab = realloc(tab, max_tab * sizeof(kon));
            }

        }
        printf("%d", max_tab);
        free(tab);
        fclose(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's text file:

```
RUMIANEK, 1998, Warsaw,
ALAMOS, 1991, Madrid,
BOSSIER, 2004, Paris,
```

There are more of them but I've shortend it a little and there is an empty line at the end.

Here's an output:

```
RUMIANEK, 1998, Warsaw
ALAMOS, 1991, Madrid
BOSSIER, 2004, Paris

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 2.122 s
Press any key to continue.
```

As you see, my program doesn't return max_tab after while loop and I don't know why.

@edit:

Added full code.

Comment: `0xC0000005` means that your program has crashed. You need to provide a self-contained example. Your current one is not self-contained - for example, we have no idea what's the definition of `line`. Good chances are, it's a `char*`, which is a problem, because it's likely uninitialized.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example, since your code crashes, but we cannot be sure from your code what is the issue, only suspect.

Comment: Added full code

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `sizeof(myStruct)`?

Comment: `fgets(line, sizeof(line), input) != EOF` is a type error. Please pay attention to your compiler diagnostics.

Comment: `if(line)` is always true.

Comment: Forgot to switch it after inserting full code. @AndrasDeak

Comment: Removed EOF and pointless if. Still there's an error. @melpomene

Comment: And you still need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure your `realloc` call succeeds?

Comment: After implementing @gsamaras answer your program works fine for me. What is the problem you are seeing when running it?

Comment: I think realloc works fine. @JohnBode

Comment: Okay, I found out that the problem was in that text file. After I downloaded it from page somehow formatting of the text was messed up and it crashed my program. Enters where changed into blank spaces (?), I don't know how to call that. When I fixed them everything worked fine. Sorry for trouble and thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), input) != EOF)
```

get rid of EOF.

Then probably you understand that this `if(line)` is not needed, as it's always evaluated to true.

Comment: Removed EOF and pointless if. The program still crashes (I forgot to switch myStruct to kon when I was inserting full code so that wasn't a problem though).